# How do I create a process in a c# program?

Tags: c#

```
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "java.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar [jar location]"
        myProcess.Start();
```

i got this code from another question on this site, but "myProcess" is never defined on there and i dont know how to define it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run a command line from c# use the following code :

```
Process.Start("java.exe", "-jar <jar name>");
```

More examples can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The type you are looking for is :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process
```

This class is well documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)